# Import a text file and export a 3D image

Tags: python, numpy, plot, 3d

What I need to do is load a txt file and make a 3D matrix for imaging.

With the code below, I'm receiving an error when the text file is a big file with lots of data.

```python
# Load a .txt data output from tomoview into a volume

import numpy as np
from tifffile import imsave
import io


#number of elements in array
i = 128

#open the text file with all headers
data = io.open('BreastPhantomTest.txt','r',encoding='cp1252')

#create a list of all lines with data in them - the typical format is for 16 lines of header, 
#followed by 'n' lines of data each 'm' tab delimited data points long 
#where 'n' is the number of points in the scan direction and 'm' is the number of digitization points
#This repeats for each 'i element.

#line = data.readlines() ##-- this method will get slow for larger datasets I believe
datatrimmed=[]
#assume lines with data start with a non-zero number this should scale up in data size.
#We can also use this method to get other parameters out of the header.
for line in data:
    #line = line.rstrip()
    if not line[0].isdigit():continue #take only the digits
    #if not line[0]!='0':continue #take only the lines that don't start with a zero.
    f = line.split()
    datatrimmed.append(f)



m = len(f)    
volume = np.reshape(datatrimmed,(i,m,-1)) #create the volume, leaving the number of scan points to float
volume1=np.float32(volume)
imsave('volume.tiff',volume1)
```

The error I receive is this:

> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged as "volume =
>   np.reshape(datatrimmed,(i,m,-1)) #create the volume, leaving the
>   number of scan points to float"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your value for i is too big for the reshape that you are doing.

P.S. 
Numpy's [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) will take care a lot of this work for you. You can specify the number of header rows to skip.

```
import numpy as np

with open('BreastPhantomTest.txt','r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    data = np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=16)

data = data[np.where(data[:, 0] != 0)].astype('float32') # filter out lines starting with 0

i = 128
m = data.shape[1]
assert data.shape[0] <= i, "Your value for i is too big"
data = data.reshape(i, m, -1)
```

Comment: Yes, this file contains a lot of data which in some the data are missing, and hence the size of the matrix could not be calculated beautifully. Now I am trying the very old way to set array for each line of data and put them in a matrix. that is a big work